# dynamic table text search

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to dynamically filter table cell contents according to a search box.

I have a table which has several [3 cell] rows. Each cell is independent, and there is a username in each cell.

I would like all the cells to disappear except the one(s) that match the search criteria.

I already looked here but no luck (it makes the entire row disappear, instead of a single cell):

http://www.marceble.com/2010/02/simple-jquery-table-row-filter/

any help is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you took the code on the website you mentioned:

```
//hide all the rows
$("#fbody").find("tr").hide();
//split the current value of searchInput
var data = this.value.split(" ");
//create a jquery object of the rows
var jo = $("#fbody").find("tr");
```

To

```
//hide all the rows
$("#fbody").find("td").hide();
//split the current value of searchInput
var data = this.value.split(" ");
//create a jquery object of the rows
var jo = $("#fbody").find("td");
```

This would hide TDs instead of TRs. But it may make the formatting funky, I would test it out first.

Comment: thanks for the answer, that is exactly what I did 3 minutes ago! The problem is that I need a way to reorder the resulting cells (move them upwards in the table, as currently they just don't move and there are holes in the resulting table!)

Comment: ok, now it works.. I just had multiple checkboxes with the same value which led to errors of course! thanks!